# Error while interating javascript arraylist using jquery $each

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]Hi I am developing mobile web application using HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery and Jquery Mobile.  I am using javascript ArrayList to store and retrieve data.

```
var SampleArray= [];

SampleArray[SampleArray.length] = { Id: 1, Name: 'Kanna' };
```

Before start iterating like below, in mobile device  aw,snap error is coming

```
$.each(SampleArray, function (i,v) { 
      alert(SampleArray[i].Name);//Here output is coming
});
```

any other alternate solution is available for this issue.

Please give suggestion for this issue.

**Edited**
I have created single page application.Some times the issue is coming.

Any other possibility is there to avoid this issue.

Sorry Friends the issue occured because i have created more objects for a function in a page that is what.

Comment: Working here.. http://jsfiddle.net/2owcgbpx/

Comment: no array is a variable

Comment: @AbdulJabbar it will work some time it is crashing.And I have created single page application.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is a keyword in JavaScript, if you change the variable name to something different, it would work:

```
var randomName= [];

randomName[randomName.length] = { Id: 1, Name: 'Kanna' };

$.each(randomName, function (i) { 

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `Array` is a keyword as in `var myArray = new Array();`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vtbutnn/)

```
var myArray = [];

myArray[myArray.length] = { Id: 1, Name: 'Kanna' };

$.each(myArray, function (i, e) { 
    alert(e.Name);
});
```

Comment: Actually, `Array` is a constructor for `Array`s and is also a reserved keyword.